# Import to list from csv file does not import all excel items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Question regarding import to list. I have a PowerShell script that builds a csv file. The csv file contains around 74 rows in it.

When I import the csv file to a SharePoint list using the Import Spreadsheet to list template, two things happens:
1) Once it is finish, I get a 403 error.
2) The import only displays 30 out of the 74 rows.

I don't know why this is. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not aware of any limitations, but I am sure there are some - there always is...I might look at row 29-31 to see if any of the data in either of those rows is larger than any of the preceding rows.  Perhaps get some metrics on each colum of data by opening the CSV in Excel and adding a string length function for each cell of data.  If it's not a data length thing, it might be a formatting thing.  Perhaps the first 30 lines (or so) have a column that appears to be a date, but on or about line 30, there is a NULL or misformatted date.

Answer (score 2):

I have never had great luck with that feature in SharePoint. I created a PowerShell script that will reach a CSV and copy all the items into your list. Check it out at http://sp2010adminpack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Import-DataIntoSharePoint&referringTitle=Documentation

HTH